# Join whole word by its Tag Python

Tags: python, regex, string

let say i have this sentences:

```
His/O name/O is/O Petter/Name Jack/Name and/O his/O brother/O name/O is/O 
Jonas/Name Van/Name Dame/Name
```

How can i get result like this:

```
Petter Jack, Jonas Van Dame.
```

So far i've already tried this, but still its just join 2 word :

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"\w+\/Name)
sent = sentence.split()
for i , w in sent:
    if pattern.match(sent[i]) != None:
        if pattern.match(sent[i+1]) != None:
        #....
        #join sent[i] and sent[i+1] element
        #....
```

Comment: why do you split sentence ? can't you use re directly on all text ?

Comment: i know, i just using another method works to combine. still dont know how to join by its tag by using whole text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
pattern = re.compile(r"((\w+\/Name\s*)+)")
names = pattern.findall(your_string)
for name in names:
    print(''.join(name[0].split('/Name')))
```

Comment: i've been tried this. but the result is single word. And i want to join one person name. If i try to join this, i cant specify the other names

Comment: Okay, give me a second ))

Comment: you saved my day. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking about a two-phase solution

```
r = re.compile(r'\w+\/Name(?:\ \w+\/Name)*')    
result = r.findall(s)
# -> ['Petter/Name Jack/Name', 'Jonas/Name Van/Name Dame/Name']

for r in result:
    print(r.replace('/Name', ''))
# -> Petter Jack
# -> Jonas Van Dame
```